# Copy and Paste Rows but not overwrite the hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to say thank you for the help I've been getting lately. So I am testing the VBA and I noticed that when I copy and paste data to the worksheet, it would overwrite the hidden rows. Is there a way to copy and paste the data without overwriting the hidden rows?

```
Public Sub CNPInStock()    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)       'Last Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)   'Second to Last Worksheet

    lr1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws2.Range("A1:C" & lr2).Autofilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    ws2.Range("A2:C" & lr2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ws1.Range("A" & lr1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the issue with finding the last row that also takes into account hidden rows? If so, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) has just about every method documented. I believe you will want to use the `Find` method to get the last row that also considers hidden rows. (See the section `Find Last Row in a Sheet` under Siddharth's solution)

Answer (score 0):

It is the same behavior as with normal copy and paste operation done without VBA.

While you *can* simultaneously copy data from the multiple rows by **Selecting visible cells** and then **Copying**, you *cannot* **Paste** into multiple regions with one single operation (if some rows are filtered out, this is basically what you are trying to do).

You need to loop with `For ... Next` through each row to paste the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following solution will help you:

```
Sub CNPInStock()

   'source-sheet
   Dim sws As Worksheet
   'target-sheet
   Dim tws As Worksheet

   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long

   Dim iEnd As Long

   Set sws = Sheets("Source")
   Set tws = Sheets("Target")


   'only for faster calculation
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   'get end of source-sheet
   iEnd = sws.Range("A" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'init row for target-sheet
   j = 1

   'loop the source-sheet
   For i = 1 To iEnd

       'your filter in column 3 with value > 0
       If sws.Cells(i, 3).Value > 0 Then

           'check if row in target-sheet is hidden
           Do Until tws.Rows(j).Hidden = False
               j = j + 1
           Loop

           'copy source to target
           sws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy Destination:=tws.Cells(j, 1)

           j = j + 1
       End If
   Next i


   'back to automatic (slower) calculation
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```